# What do you call something that has a lot of features?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Simply put, let's say I want to advertise my app, and I want to say it is full of features. Is there a word that I can replace "full of features" with? And how can I say "it is the app with the most features" but in a more formal manner? Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Hello and welcome!  Generally, EL&U is not a site for providing branding or marketing advice.  However, since your question is clear to me, I would suggest "**feature-rich**"

Comment: "multi" is a good prefix to try.  "multi-featured", I think gets the point across simply and clearly.

Answer (score 4):

> The Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers defines the term feature in IEEE 829 as "*A distinguishing characteristic of a software item (e.g., performance, portability, or functionality)*."
>
> A system is said to be **feature-rich** when it has many options and functional capabilities available to the user. [...] 
>   Sometimes if a piece of software is very feature-rich, that can be seen as a bad thing - see feature creep and software bloat.
>   — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_feature)

Answer (score 1):

**featureful** (in addition to *feature-rich*).

> Adjective
>   **featureful** (comparative more featureful, superlative most featureful)
>
> (chiefly computing) Having many features.

-- [Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/featureful)

---

> Adjective
>
> (comparative more featureful, superlative most featureful)
>
> (chiefly computing) Having many features.

-- [yourdictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/featureful)

Answer (score 1):

*Feature-rich* is definitely the modern term for this.  If you want something more timeless:

***versatile***

> 2. Having varied uses or serving many functions: "The most versatile of vegetables is the tomato." *(American Heritage)*

Answer (score 0):

> **Multifaceted**
> [muhl-tee-fas-i-tid, muhl-tahy-]/
> adjective
>
> 1. having many facets, as a gem.
> 2. having many aspects or phases